# .toArray(callback) mongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

I try to get document by query from mongoDB using nodejs but it works weird.
When I try to get all docs it works fine.
now I have two exactly same functions byt one of them returns all collection, another does not returns anything! promise does not resolved! help me pls

database file:

```
module.exports.getAll = (database, collection, query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            dbclient
                .db(database)
                .collection(collection)
                .find({ word: query })
                .toArray(function (err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                    }
                    resolve(results);
                })
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    })
}

module.exports.getByQuery = (database, collection, query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            dbclient
                .db(database)
                .collection(collection)
                .find({ word: query })
                .toArray(function (err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                    }
                    resolve(results);
                })
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    })
}
```

model file:

```
module.exports.getByQuery = async (collection, query) => {
    return await mongoDB.getByQuery(config.mongoDB.databaseName, collection, query);
}

module.exports.getAll = async (collection, query) => {
    return await mongoDB.getAll(config.mongoDB.databaseName, collection, query)
}
```

controller file:

```
console.log(await searchModel.getAll('InvertedIndex', 'положение'));
console.log(await searchModel.getByQuery('InvertedIndex', 'положение'));
```

query is fine, I try it in Compass

I have no errors

does not work only block `function (err, results) { if (err) { reject(err) } resolve(results); }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        dbclient
            .db(database)
            .collection(collection)
            .find({ word: query })
            .toArray().then((results) {
                resolve(results);
            }).catch((err) => {
              reject(err)
            })
```